# Can I change what displays in the 'Model' field in the printer directory when using a universal/basic driver?

Tags: windows-server-2012, drivers, print-server

I have a few printers on a Server 2012 print server that make use of "universal" drivers from the manufacturer.

When using drivers like these, the description field for the model is sometimes set to the driver name, for example:

[image]

This matches what's displayed in the printers' properties pages under 'Model':

[image]

Is there any way to change that model field to that *actual* model name, without changing the driver? I'd rather my users see the actual model name there if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Windows gets the model name from the driver itself, I know the HP setup allows you to show the driver for the printer, or as a generic driver. You might be able to do that here as well but you would need to re-install your printers.